# Had anyone managed to get amaterasERD working with Aptana Studio?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aptana

Hey. Call me dumb but I can not get amaterasERD working with Aptana Studio under OS X.Is this doable? I have Aptana 2.04. I've installed amaterasERD, GEF, EMF, UML2 and AmaterasUMLExtension. No joy. Am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some troubles too. The problem seems to be with Aptana, since under "pure Eclipse", AmaterasERD seems to work without problems for me.